# Scraping a number from a span tag (no id nor class) contained within div tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to scrape a website.

The website is an online casino (https://www.888casino.it/live-casino/#filters=all-roulette), and I need to scrape **just one** of the numbers displayed (the number contained in a particular position changes more or less every 30 seconds, but I will think about this later).

```
<div class="sc-qbELi jLgZIw">
  <span>2</span>
</div>
```

The number I want to scrape is contained within span tags, which I am unable to locate as they have no id or class. As a consequence, I tought about locating the div tag that contains the span tag, and then scraping the number contained in the span tags using functions such as .contents or .next_element or .children

In order to locate the div tag (it is not the first div tag in the html code, and it is located within many other div tags):

- I imported the modules and set the link to the webpage:

  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  import requests

  import urllib.request

  url = 'https://www.888casino.it/live-casino/#filters=all-roulette'

  response = requests.get(url)

  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
- I tried the following three solutions:

.

```
div_tag = soup.findAll('div', class_='sc-qbELi jLgZIw')

div_tag = soup.find("div", class_="sc-qbELi jLgZIw")

div_tag = soup.select("div.jLgZIw.sc-qbELi")
```

The problem is that when printed, these lines of codes' output is respectively: [ ], None, [ ].
So when I try to add .children or .content to div_tag, I don't get anything as well.

I would be glad if you could help me figure out how to do this.
Thanks for your attention

Comment: try finding all div without the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use selenium. The website is most likely dynamically loaded

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://www.888casino.it/live-casino/#filters=all-roulette'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Using

```
len(soup.find_all(class_="sc-qbELi jLgZIw"))
```

gives length of 50. You'd have to figure out how to get the right one, but this yields the output to get you started